# One url for two different views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls, django-1.7

I'm developing a site that have two types of User, and the project's owners want two different home (templates) after the user is authenticated, so, I tried this:

url

```
# home a
url(r'^home/$', HomeAView.as_view(), name='home-a'),
# home b
url(r'^home/$', HomeBView.as_view(), name='home-b'),
```

And some like that at into my log_in view:

```
if user.typeUser == "HA":
    print('Go to Home A')
    return redirect(reverse('sesion:home-a'))
else:
    print('Go to Home B')
    return redirect(reverse('sesion:home-b'))
```

So the problem is that after the user is authenticated, the site always go to the first url! (Home A) I printed by console a little flag and the conditional is working, and pass by sesion:home-a or home-b, but always go to home-a. Why reverse don't resolve the url, if I assigned different names? Can't I have one url for two views??

Thanks for your help, I'm working on Django 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot have two different views for the same URL. Django decides which view function to use according to the URL and the routes defined.

Use custom code inside an unique view to render a different template depending on the type of user:

```
def home(request):
    if user.typeUser == "HA":
        render(request, 'template_a.html')
    else:
        render(request, 'template_b.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! But, I read this docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/ and, I understand that it's possible, I separated home-a into a different app, and I add the namespace, but don't work, I redirect to test:home-a, and sesion:home-b, but always go to Home A...

Comment: You can have the same _URL name_ (the `name` argument in the `url` function) for different views using different namespaces, but you can't have the same working _URL regex pattern_ (first argument of `url` function) pointing to two different views. Django will have to arbitrarily decide which view to use.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a class based view implementation, you can override the `get_template_names` method for any view that inherits the `TemplateResponseMixin`and return a list of strings. The template names will be searched in that order until one matches or `ImproperlyConfigured` is raised

```
class Home(TemplateResponseMixin):
   ...
   def get_template_names(self):
      if self.request.user.typeUser == "HA":
         return ['template_a.html']
      else:
         return ['template_b.html']
```