# How To use multiple url with the same template file in django.?

Tags: python, django, url

**URLS.PY**

```
url(r'^shop.html$', views.alldress, name='alldress'),
url(r'^shop.html$', views.cart ,name='cart'),
url(r'^shop.html$', views.cartdata, name='cartdata'),
```

I want to use three process with the same time so How To use multiple url with the same template file in django.?

Comment: Same template file? You probably mean the same URL, and this makes no sense. What view should be triggered if a user visits `shop.html`? If all three should be started, then what view should respond?

Comment: check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571759/one-url-for-two-different-views

Comment: The idea is that you have one view for a URL, that returns a response, it can of course call utility functions (and even other views), and then "merge these" results. I think here however you might perhaps want to produce a page where an AJAX request for example later loads the `'cartdata'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have only one html file name is shop.html I want to use three different type of view function in single html file

Answer (score 3):

In Django, the `urls.py` file is meant to connect URL patterns with a view function. If you have multiple URL patterns that are meant to do the same thing, just connect them all to the same view function, like so:

```
url(r'^shop/$', views.shop, name='shop'),
url(r'^cart/$', views.shop, name='cart'),
url(r'^cartdata/$', views.shop, name='cartdata')
```

If you want your URL patterns to do different things but still render the same template, you can just render that template in each of your `views.py` functions.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^shop/$', views.shop, name='shop'),
url(r'^cart/$', views.cart, name='cart'),
url(r'^cartdata/$', views.cartdata, name='cartdata')

# views.py
def shop(request):
    context = {}
    ...
    return render(request, 'shop.html', context)

def cart(request):
    context = {}
    ...
    return render(request, 'shop.html', context)

def cartdata(request):
    context = {}
    ...
    return render(request, 'shop.html', context)
```

In this example, each of the three views.py functions perform different operations, but they all render the same HTML file, `shop.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have only one html file name is shop.html I want to use three different type of view function in single html file..

Comment: You can! Check my edited answer for a more fleshed out example. Is that what you're looking for? You can have any number of Django views returning the same template.